# Override color on ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, plot, colors, ggplot2, legend

I am manually adding a legend to `ggplot2` and would like to change the color associated with the legend. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100), y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = rnorm(100))
dat1 <- dat[,c(1,2,3)]

mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x + z, data = dat1)

dat1$mod1 <- predict(mod1, newdata =dat1)  
err <- predict(mod1, newdata =dat1, se = TRUE)   
dat1$ucl <- err$fit + 1.96 * err$se.fit
dat1$lcl <- err$fit - 1.96 * err$se.fit   


var<- "Var"
col <- "green"
ggplot(dat1, aes(x = x)) + 
        geom_point(aes(x = x, y = mod1, fill = "X"), size = .8, colour = "red") +
        geom_smooth(data = dat1, aes(x= x, y = mod1, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), size = 1, colour = "blue", se = TRUE, stat = "smooth", method = "lm")+ 
        scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", limits = var, values = col)
```

With this code the legend remains red rather than green. Any idea of why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Because you didn't use a symbol that can be filled?  The whole point is colored red - change pch to 21 to see the difference.

Comment: I meant change your `shape` to 21 (although you can use `pch` as well).